# Constant in the Poincare inequality for curl square integrable vector fields

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

$\newcommand{\v}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}$For an $u\in H^1(\Omega) = W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is Lipschitz, we have

$$
{\|u - \frac{1}{\left|\Omega\right|} \int_{\Omega} u\|}_{L^2}\leq C
{\|\nabla u \|}
$$

and the Poincare constant is basically a multiple of diameter of the domain.

However in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the only similar result for $\mathbf{curl}$-square integrable vector fields $\v{u}$ would be:

$$
{\|\v{u} - \frac{1}{\left|\Omega\right|} \int_{\Omega} \v{u}\|}_{L^2} \leq {\|\mathbf{curl}  \ \v{u}\|}
$$

if $\v{u}$ is divergence free.

If not, suppose $\v{u}$'s divergence is not well-defined, then we could have:

$$
{\|\v{u} - \frac{1}{\left|\Omega\right|} \int_{\Omega} \v{u}\|}_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq 
C_1 \left(\|\v{u}\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2+{\|\mathbf{curl}  \ \v{u}\|}^2 \right)^{1/2}
$$

Since we could still do Helmholtz decomposition $\v{u} = \v{w}+\nabla p$, qualitatively speaking, locally in the a compact subdomain $K\subset \Omega$, if the $\v{u}$ is more irrotational(that gradient field $\nabla p$ is dominant), then $C_1$ is closed to $1$, if the $\v{u}$ is more weakly-solenoidal($\v{w}$ is dominant), then the $C_1$ is more closed to $\sqrt{1+d^2}$.

I am curious if we could decompose the domain $\Omega$ into different parts, such that we estimate the Poincare constant locally and then put together to get a sharper bound?

Comment: I don't quite grok your paragraph starting "Since we could..." Isn't $w$ the divergence free part? Then when $w$ is dominant, shouldn't you get closer to the divergence free case, and the reverse when $\nabla p$ is dominant? 

Comment: BTW, have you seen http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.6045 ?

Comment: @Willie Wong, thanks for the comment, the main reason I am doing this is because I want to circumvent the divergence part, since for general $H(\mathbf{curl})$ vector fields, the divergence is not defined, and $w$ is in the weakly divergence free, such that I could get a Poincare inequality solely for $H(\mathbf{curl})$ vector fields not having the divergence free constraint. Thanks for the heads up of the uniformity paper as well, I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are trying to say in your third  inequality, as $C_1$ is always $1$.
Consider the minimization problem
$$
I_u=\inf_{k\in\mathbb R} \left\| u -k \right\|_{L^2(\mathbb \Omega)}^2
$$
On one hand, it is clear that $I_u \leq \left\| u \right\|_{L^2(\mathbb \Omega)}^2$, since this upper bound corresponds to $k=0$. On the other hand, since
$$
\left\| u -k \right\|_{L^2(\mathbb \Omega)}^2 = k^2 \left|\Omega\right| -2 k \int_\Omega u ~\text d x+  \int_\Omega u^2 \text d x
$$
the infimum is a minimum corresponding to $k= \frac 1 {\left|\Omega\right|} \int_\Omega u \text d x$
thus
$$
\left\| u -\frac 1 {\left|\Omega\right|} \int_\Omega u ~\text d x \right\|_{L^2(\mathbb \Omega)} \leq \left\| u \right\|_{L^2(\mathbb \Omega)},
$$
and equality is attained for any function with zero average. Surely you meant something else?